# Trying to create a desktop application in C++ on visual studio

Tags: c++, desktop

I'm trying to program a desktop application that will eventually communicate with an arduino (which has not come in yet) to control LED lights around my room and PC. I am on microsoft's page on how to create a desktop application and have copied 99% of this program off them so I could play around with it and see what it does. However I cannot even run the thing because of 2 issues.

1. When I try to use WndProc it says "function definition for WndProc not found and,

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    _In_ HWND   hWnd,
    _In_ UINT   message,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

2. When I try to use WinMain it says "Inconsistent annotation for WinMain: this instance has no annotations"

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
```

Here is the full source code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("Colour Control");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Colour Control 1.0");

HINSTANCE hInst;

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    _In_ HWND   hWnd,
    _In_ UINT   message,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }



    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application dows not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }
    // Store instance handle in our global variable
    hInst = hInstance;

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio comes with generators that will give you working code to start with. Use those. Also, consider using a widget kit like MFC or WCF that VS offers, it makes many things easier to start with.

Answer (score 0):

why are you defining WinMain and WndProc in your .cpp file. You should not do that instead you have to provide only definition of these functions. Like for WindowsProc

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
          //Code 
          break;                  
        case WM_CLOSE:
          DestroyWindow(hwnd);
          break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          break;
        default:
          return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    } 
    return 0;
```

}

You have to delete deceleration of WndProc and WinMain.

Comment: How would I do this for WinMain? I'm completely new to this so sorry in advance

Comment: Just remove the deceleration, rest will be fine.